# .NET Garbage Collection (GC) Tuning

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, performance

I have situation when GC has no time to delete free objects. The code loads a large document into memory and processes it in a loop. If I stop in this loop (in debug mode) or add GC.Collect() the memory usage drops to less then 70 MB.

How do I tune GC? Are there any best practices for tuning GC?

Comment: Can you give more details about your scenario and how the GC affects your application? How do you know that GC "has not time" to delete objects?

Comment: Can't say I've ever tunned anything, let alone the GC.  However, if you do a bit of searching around here, you'll find there's an overwhelming best practice of DON'T DO IT.  TUNE your application to allocate and `Dispose()` properly and the GC will work with you.

Comment: code reads big document into memory and process it, so in one of method presents loop where doing process of this document. If I stopped in this loop(in debug mode) or add GC.Collect() memory less then 70 MB.

Comment: And if you don't help in the loop, what is the exact problem?

Comment: Why does this high memory usage matter? The GC will get rid of it if it needs to. Most of the time, it doesn't need to, so it leaves it alone.

Comment: @Jesse: No, `Dispose` has nothing to do with GC.

Comment: @thecoop: We just found a really serious bug in the .NET 4 concurrent workstation GC on x64. This is supposed to be the nearest thing .NET has to a low latency GC but, when this bug manifests, it leaks memory until all physical memory has been exhausted (consuming in excess of 11Gb of RAM here) and does one mammoth GC cycle to clear it out, pausing the entire application for up to two minutes (!) until the entire process is repeated. Suffice to say, this is a catastrophe for distributed concurrent systems like ours because connections time out.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: that would be a good example of when it _is_ justified to call GC.Collect() manually, maybe limiting to a specific generation so you're not doing a full collection of generation 2.

Comment: @thecoop: Unfortunately that wouldn't solve our problem because collecting anything below gen2 doesn't fix the leak and collecting gen2 overshoots our latency requirements by an order of magnitude. Otherwise, it could be an adequate workaround for the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tuning here is to leave it alone.

But if your process is really blocking the GC all the time (it shouldn't), it could help to call `GC.Collect()` *after* some memory consuming part finishes.

But we need a lot more info here. What type of application, why (do you think) the GC has no time to do it normally?

Comment: yes, I know about it, but call Collect method is bed practice or isn't ?

Comment: @jitm: Yes it in general a bad practice. You need to provide a lot more info before someone can say if it would be a solution for you.

Comment: I've  added some informations as comment above. In general process big file in memory.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to explore what is happening inside the garbage collector when your program is running. Usually garbage collector is good at deciding when to remove objects without your intervention.  However, it is not error prone. For example, you may be keeping a list of small objects that hold references to large objects that you expect to die soon. To understand the bottlenecks in GC you need to profile GC memory allocation. To do this...

1 ) Search "performance monitor" in windows start

2)Under monitoring tools tab select performance monitor. Clear any counters you already have by "right click-> remove all counters"

3)right click ->add counters

4) Select all the counters under ".NET CLR  memory". When you add them make sure you start your program and select the program from the list to your left side. This will make sure your counters are going to report the performance of your program but not anything else

5) Once you have your counters running please read following articles to find the bottle necks in your program.

**Garbage collector basics**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

**What performance monitor counters tell you**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx
http://netrsc.blogspot.com.es/2008/01/net-clr-memory-performance-monitoring.html

Once you are familiar with basics look for following issues
1) Large object heap is fragmenting too quickly

2) Objects you want to die fast end up in generation 2
E.g. mid-life crisis http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/04/41281.aspx

3) Total committed bytes keep increasing

4) You spend too much time garbage collecting

5) and many more... (google for GC memory issues)

Since you can't identify which objects live in different generations you can use something like ANST memory profile to see whether you  are inadvertently promoting short lived objects into generation 2. The profiler allows you to see who holds references to large objects and peak into different garbage collector storages (e.g who live in generation 2 who live is large object heap). But before doing any advance performance tuning use windows performance monitor to identify whether your bottlenecks are in fact with GC.